# Charged particle complex motion in magnetic field (Taiwan Physics Olympiad final 2018)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image: Taiwan Olympiad final 2018]

Disregarding all the problems except the last one. The last problem seems complex for me. A closed curve means that the motion is periodic so that at certain time T ,z spirals backs to it original position and $$\phi(t+T)=\phi(t)+2n\pi\;\;with\;n\;being\;integer$$
$$z(t+T)=z(t)$$
Using this kind of technique will involve very complex integral. It's a contest for olympiad so it's probably related to simplification of (C) to simple harmonic equation but there is no way to replace sinx with x since we have no idea whether \phi is small enough. Does anyone know how to solve the last problem?

Comment: Numerical analysis strongly suggests to me that *all* curves are closed for part (e), with period Re(4$K(\omega_c^2/\omega_\phi^2)$), where $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: Is the answer $\omega_c \leq \omega_{\phi}$?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Here's a better answer.  See below for original full analytic solution.

## Parts (a) and (b)

Let's first re-derive (a) - (c) to make sure we know what's going on.  I don't know the Taiwan Physics Olympiad, but my guess is that Lagrangian classical mechanics is fair game.  So let's find the Euler-Lagrange EOM.  The Lagrangian for a charged particle in a magnetic field is given by $$L = \frac1 2mv^2+q\dot{\vec{v}}\cdot \vec A.$$  If $\vec B = B\hat x = \vec\nabla\times\vec A,$ then $\vec A = By\hat z$ gives the correct magnetic field.

Changing to the generalized coordinates $\phi$ and $z$ we have that $$L = \frac1 2 m(R_0^2\dot\phi^2+\dot z^2)+qBR_0\sin\phi\dot z.$$

We immediately see that the Lagrangian is independent of $z$, and therefore $$p_z\equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot z} = m\dot z+qBR_0\sin\phi = const.$$  Defining $\omega_c\equiv qB/m$ the above implies that when $\phi(t=0)=0$ then $$\dot z+\omega_cR_0\sin\phi = R_0\omega_z,$$ where $\omega_z$ is defined by $$\dot z(t=0) \equiv R_0\omega_z.$$

Moving on, the EL EOM for $\phi$ yields $$R_0^2\ddot\phi-\omega_cR_0\cos\phi\dot z = 0.$$

We've thus successfully shown (a) and (b).

## Part (c)

A fundamental result in Lagrangian mechanics is that when the Lagrangian does not explicitly depend on time, the Hamiltonian is conserved, where $H = \dot q_j\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_j} -L$.  We may compute the Hamiltonian in a straightforward way: $$H = (m\dot z + qBR_0\sin\phi)\dot z+mR_0^2\dot\phi^2-\big[ 
\frac1 2m(R_0^2\dot\phi^2+\dot z^2)+qBR_0\sin\phi\dot z \big] = E = const$$ $$\Rightarrow\qquad \frac1 2 \dot z^2+\frac1 2 R_0^2\dot\phi^2 = \frac E m.$$  At $t=0$ we have that $\dot z = R_0\omega_z$ and $\dot\phi\equiv\omega_\phi$.  Thus at $t=0$ we have that $$R_0^2\omega_z^2+R_0^2\omega_\phi^2 = \frac{2E}{m}.$$  Therefore for all $t$ we have that $$R_0^2(\omega_z-\omega_c\sin\phi)^2+R_0^2\dot\phi^2 = R_0^2(\omega_z^2+\omega_\phi^2)$$ which implies that $$-2\omega_z\omega_c\sin\phi+\omega_c^2\sin^2\phi+\dot\phi^2=\omega_\phi^2.$$  We've thus shown (c).

## Part (d)

Presumably the graders are thinking of a helix as defined by $\dot z = const$ and $\dot \phi = const$.  From (b) and (c), we can easily see that the $z$ and $\phi$ velocities are 0 iff $\omega_c=0$.

## Part (e)

Ok, now for the fun part.  Let's first try to get some physical intuition for the result.

### Strong field limit

Consider first the case in which the angular deflection is small, $\phi\ll1$.  Then the equations of motion are, to leading order in $\phi$, $$\ddot\phi = -\omega_c^2\phi \\ \dot z = -\omega_cR_0\phi,$$ which implies that for $\dot\phi(0)=\omega_\phi$, $\phi(0)=0$, $\dot z(0)=R_0\omega_z$, $z(0)=0$, then $$\phi(t) = \frac{\omega_\phi}{\omega_c}\sin(\omega_c t) \\ z(t) = \frac{\omega_\phi}{\omega_c}R_0\big(\cos(\omega_ct)-1\big).$$

We see that in order for the angle to be small, $\phi\ll1$, we must have that $r\gg1$, where $r\equiv \omega_c/\omega_\phi$.  We'll call the limit in which $r\gg1$ the *strong field* limit, since this limit implies that $qB/m$ is large compared to the initial angular velocity.  What's happening here physically is that the charged particle is executing little circles around the $\hat x$ axis.

### Weak field limit

Let's now imagine that the motion is periodic with $$\phi(t) = \frac{t}{T_\phi} + A\sin\big(\frac{t}{T_\phi}\big),\qquad A\ll 1 \\ z(t) = \omega_c T_\phi R_0\big(\cos(\frac{t}{T_\phi})-1\big) + \mathcal{O}(A).$$  Since $\dot\phi(0)=\omega_\phi = \frac{1+A}{T_\phi}$, we must have $A = \omega_\phi T_\phi-1\ll1$.  Thus $T_\phi=1/\omega_\phi$.  Referring back to the EOM for $\phi$, $\ddot\phi\sim A$ while $\omega_c^2\sin\phi\cos\phi\sim A^0$.  Thus we must have that $$\ddot\phi\sim\frac{A}{T_{\phi}^2}\sim\omega_c^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad A\sim\omega_c^2T_\phi^2\sim\frac{\omega_c^2}{\omega_\phi^2}\ll1.$$  Thus our *weak field* limit corresponds to $r\ll1$, in which case $qB/m$ is small compared to the initial angular velocity.  In this case, the charged particle goes around the nanotube.

### Proof of closure of curves

**Case 1: r < 1**

Consider first the case that $r<1$.  Then from $\dot\phi^2 = \omega_\phi\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi}$ we have that $$\int_0^t dt' = \frac{1}{\omega_\phi}\int_0^{\phi(t)}\frac{d\phi'}{\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi'}}.$$  It's pretty clear that for $r<1$ the right hand side can be evaluated (in principle) without difficulty; i.e. there aren't any singularities in the integrand.  As time increases, $\phi$ increases.  We even have a closed-form expression for the period, $$t_{2\pi}\equiv\frac{1}{\omega_\phi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi'}{\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi'}}.$$

Let's now see what happens with $z(t)$.  We have that $$\frac{dz}{d\phi}=\frac{dz}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\phi} = -\omega_c R_0\sin\phi\frac{1}{\omega_\phi\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi}} \\ \Rightarrow \qquad \int_0^{z(\phi)}dz' = z(\phi) = -r R_0\int_0^\phi \frac{\sin\phi'd\phi'}{\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi'}}.$$  Let's now plug in $\phi=2\pi$ into the last equation.  If we think a little bit about the integrand on the right hand side of the equation, we know that $\sin\phi'$ is an odd function about $\phi'=\pi$ while $1-r^2\sin^2\phi'$ is an even function about $\phi'=\pi$.  Thus the right hand side evaluates to 0 and we have that $z(2\pi) = 0 = z(0)$.  Thus every curve is closed for $r<1$.

**Case 2: r > 1**

Consider now the case that $r>1$.  Now we have that there's a $\phi_{max}$ for which $$\dot\phi^2=\omega_\phi^2(1-r^2\sin^2\phi_{\max}) = 0.$$  For $\phi<\phi_{\max}$, $\dot\phi = \omega_\phi\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi}$.

What happens when $\phi = \phi_{max}$?  Going back to the EOM, $$\ddot\phi(\phi_{max}) = \frac{\omega_c}{R_0}\cos(\phi_{max})\dot z(\phi_{max}) \\ = -\frac{\omega_c^2}{2}\sin(2\phi_{max}).$$  Since $\phi_max = \sin^{-1}(1/r)<\pi/2$ for $r>1$ we have that $\ddot\phi(\phi_{max})<0$ for $r>1$.

We conclude that $\phi$ increases from 0 at $t=0$ up to $\phi_{max}$ at time $t_*$, after which $\phi$ decreases back to 0 by time $t=2t_*$.  Then the motion of $\phi$ flips: $\phi$ decreases from 0 down to $-\phi_{max}$ at time $t=3t_*$ and then increases back up to 0 at time $t=4t_*$.

What is $z(4t_*)$?  If it's 0, and $t_*<\infty$, then we know that the curve is closed.  We may compute $t_*$ using the formula above for the time given $\phi$, $$t_{*} = \int_0^{\phi_{max}}\frac{d\phi'}{\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi'}}.$$  Since the integrand is only mildly divergent at the $\phi_{max}$ endpoint, the integral converges for $r>1$.  Let's now find $z(4t_*)$.  We have that $$z(4t_*) = -rR_0\big\{ \int_0^{\phi_{max}}\frac{\sin\phi'd\phi'}{\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi'}}  - \int_{\phi_{max}}^0\frac{\sin\phi'd\phi'}{\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi'}} \\ - \int_0^{-\phi_{max}}\frac{\sin\phi'd\phi'}{\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi'}} + \int_{-\phi_{max}}^0\frac{\sin\phi'd\phi'}{\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\phi'}}\big\}.$$  If one performs a change of variables $\phi'= -\phi'$ in the latter two terms of the above, one sees that there's an exact cancellation and $z(4t_*)=0$.  Therefore all curves are closed for $r>1$.

**Case 3: r = 1**

Our guess here is that it'll take infinitely long for the charged particle to reach $\phi_{max}$, which in this case is $\pi/2.$  We may show that this is indeed the case by examining $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\phi'}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\phi'}} = \int_0^1\frac{du}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$ under the substitution $u = \sin\phi'$.  The latter integral is clearly log divergent from the lower bound.  Thus $t_*=\infty$ and the curve isn't closed.

## Full solution using special functions

The second order ODE $$\ddot\phi(t)=-\omega_c^2\sin\big(\phi(t)\big)\cos\big(\phi(t)\big)$$ $$\dot\phi(0)=\omega_\phi$$ $$\phi(0)=0,$$ which we obtain from parts (a) and (b) with $\omega_z=0$, has the solution $$\phi(t) = \mathrm{am}(\omega_\phi t|r^2),$$ where $r\equiv \omega_c/\omega_\phi$ and $\mathrm{am}(u|m)$ is the Jacobi amplitude.

The Jacobi amplitude has the following periodicity property: $\mathrm{am}\big(n4K(m)|m\big)=2\pi n$, $n\in\mathbb Z$, where $K(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

The first order ODE $$\dot z(t) = -\omega_c R_0\sin\big(\mathrm{am}(\omega_\phi t|r^2)\big)$$ $$z(0)=0$$ has the solution $$z(t)=-R_0\ln\big(\frac{\mathrm{dn}(\omega_\phi t|r^2)-r\mathrm{cn}(\omega_\phi t|r^2)}{1-r}  \big),$$ where $\mathrm{dn}(u|m)$ and $\mathrm{cn}(u|m)$ are Jacobi elliptic functions.

The Jacobi elliptic functions similarly have the periodicity property: $\mathrm{cn}\big(n4K(m)|m\big)=1=\mathrm{dn}\big(n4K(m)|m\big)$, $n\in\mathbb Z$.

From the above, we have that for any $t_n$ such that $\omega_\phi t_n = n4K(r^2)$, then $z(t_n)=0$ and $\phi(t_n)=2\pi n.$  Therefore all curves are closed for any value of $\omega_c\in\mathbb R,$ $\omega_c\ne\omega_\phi$, where the latter case is forbidden since the period $K(r^2)$ diverges for $r=1$.

It's perhaps worth noting that for $\omega_c<\omega_\phi$ the magnetic field is "weak," and the charged particle goes around the nanotube, whereas for $\omega_\phi<\omega_c$ the magnetic field is "strong," and the charged particle makes circle-like orbits that stay on only one side of the nanotube.  See figure below.
[image: 3D plots of solutions]